# Standard OData service and extended OData service

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

Does the SAP standard OData service URL still works even after extending the service? I want to extend a standard OData service keeping the standard service URL active. Creating 2 sets of applications, one runs on standard and another for customized so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your extending an OData service then you need to save that in a new location.Typically we use a Z namespace. For example, if your trying to extend service-> HCM_TIMESHEET_MAN_SRV then you would save it as ZHCM_TIMESHEET_MAN_SRV(name is completely at your discretion).

This is a very common scenario for customers who extend an existing UI5 application but still provide links to both applications in the launchpad.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question! :)